# How to turn off Pioneer 3dx rear sonars using ROSARIA?

Tags: ros, sonar, pioneer-3dx, rosaria, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Pioneer 3dx mobile robot, which has eight front sonars installed. It is also possible to have eight additional sonars at the rear of the robot, but I don't have these. However, when subscribing to the ROSARIA sonar topic, a distance is published for sixteen sonars, eight of them continuously reporting a distance of 0.

Of course, this is unwanted behavior. I could not find an appropriate parameter on the ROSARIA tutorial page, http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA.

What is the correct way to receive only distances on the sonar topic for sonars actually installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60544/how-to-turn-off-pioneer-3dx-rear-sonars-using-rosaria?/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found that ROSARIA uses the parameters from the file p3dx-sh.p at `/usr/local/Aria/params`. I changed the SonarNum on line 49 to 8 and the issue was resolved.

Looking back, it seems like a trivial question. However, I didn't find anything quickly, so I'll leave the solution here in case anyone would ever need it.

---

Originally posted by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) with karma: 386 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is something we can maybe fix in ROSARIA in a future version, I don't know when though.  (bug report is at https://code.google.com/p/amor-ros-pkg/issues/detail?id=7)

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-04-26**:
I believe a dynamic parameter server would be a nice feature, e.g. disable/enable some sonars during operation. The question is whether the default ARIA library would support dynamic parameter changes.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-04-30**:
It's easy to turn off/on all sonars. You can also effectively disable a specific sonar transducer (and change polling frequency and order) bit this would be more complicated, would you need that too?   This would be in addition to omitting data for nonexistant sonars from the 'sonar' topic.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-04-30**:
I just checked and ROSARIA ought to be disabling all the sonars on the robot if there are no subscribers to the 'sonar' topic. This is mainly just to keep it quiet if the sonars aren't actually in use.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-04-30**:
Further discussion on this could be done at  https://code.google.com/p/amor-ros-pkg/issues/detail?id=7 or https://groups.google.com/forum/?!forum/ros-sig-pioneer

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-05-01**:
I've put my comments on the amor-ros-pkg google code site. The ros-sig-pioneer forum seems inaccessible (wrong link?)